# Express e Express Generator

Tags: node.js, express.js

Entendi que o express generator só cria boilerplate pro projeto. Mas não entendi muito bem qual a forma correta de add ele no projeto

Eu preciso instalar os 2, ou só o generator já bastaria?

1. crio a pasta do projeto e dou npm init
2. npm i express --save
3. npm i express-generator --save
4. express nomeDoApp

**Não tá certo, porque agora tenho 2 package.json. 
Tem problema a node_modules ficar fora da pasta do projeto (teste-gen)?**

A estrutura de arquivos fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente não precisa criar a pasta e não precisa dar npm init, é só seguir o que a documentação fala.

**Instalar generator global**
`npm i express-generator -g`

**Verificar opções disponivel**
`express -h`

**Criar a base do projeto com view engine ejs.**

`express --view=ejs myapp`

Após este comando ele ira criar um diretório com a base do projeto, após é acessar e instalar as dependências geradas.

`npm install`

**View engine disponíveis**

`--view =
 (dust|ejs|hbs|hjs|jade|pug|twig|vash) (defaults to jade)`

Se nao setar a `--view` ele cria com a view engine jade como padrão.

**Para criar sem view definida, usar html estático**

`express -no--view myapp`

[Exemplo](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/myapp-jpg-14d501c7-1322-47a1-aefe-346973e5aa91)

Respondendo sua pergunta, você não adiciona o generator no projeto, ele cria na verdade. E pela sua imagem não há dois package.json e apenas um o outro é lock que armazena e trava as versões de cada uma das dependências instaladas. O resto fica na doc [Express generator](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/starter/generator.html)

Comment: o outro package.json tá dentro da pasta teste.

Comment: Há, ta. Agora compreendi, isso foi porque você deu npm local antes de criar a pasta do projeto.